# Insert CSV through Pandas to SQLITE: How to avoid the Memory Error?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv

I experience the memory error when trying write pandas dataframe from CSV into SQLITE database.
The CSV file has 430 MB and 6 000 000 lines.

For smaller files it works absolutely alright.
However I would like to know how to avoid the Memory error for bigger files.

The reading by chunks works fine and correctly prints 6 000 000 lines in 20 000 line chunks. However the script wants
to transfer the whole 6 000 000 lines into the SQLITE database+table  and it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/SQLITELOAD1.py", line 42, in <module>
    .rename(columns=dict(zip(big_data.columns, listofcol)))
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 197, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4025, in rename
    return super(DataFrame, self).rename(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1091, in rename
    level=level)
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 170, in rename_axis
    obj = self.copy(deep=copy)
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 734, in copy
    do_integrity_check=False)
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 395, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 753, in copy
    values = values.copy()
MemoryError
```

The code:

```
import csv, sqlite3, time, os, ctypes
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
datab = 'NORTHWIND'
con=sqlite3.connect(datab+'.db')
con.text_factory = str  
cur = con.cursor()
koko = 'C:\\NORTHWIND'
print(koko)
directory = koko 
print(directory)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    for searchfile, listofcol, table in zip(['1251_FINAL.csv'],
                                [['SYS', 'MANDT', 'AGR_NAME', 'OBJECT', 'AUTH', 'FIELD', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'DELETED']],                  
                                 ['AGR_1251_ALL2']):

                    if file.endswith(searchfile):

                            fileinsert = directory + '\\' + searchfile
                            my_list = []
                            for chunk in pd.read_csv(fileinsert, sep=",",error_bad_lines=False, encoding='latin-1', low_memory=False, chunksize=20000):
                                    my_list.append(chunk)
                                    print(chunk)
                            big_data = pd.concat(my_list, axis = 0)
                            print(big_data)
                            del my_list 
                            (big_data
                             .rename(columns=dict(zip(big_data.columns, listofcol)))
                             .to_sql(name=table,
                                    con=con,
                                     if_exists="replace",
                                     chunksize=20000,
                                     index=False,
                                     index_label=None))
```

Answer (score 4):

When you insert records in a SQL database, two sizes are to be considered:

- the size of an individual `INSERT`
- the global size between consecutive `COMMIT`

Because until the bunch of requests are commited, the database has to be able to rollback everything, so nothing is definitively written.

For the description of the symptoms, I can guess that `to_sql` uses the `chunksize` parameter as the size on an INSERT but uses one single COMMIT when the whole operation is terminated.

There is no direct fix, but the common way when loading a large record set in a database is to use intermediary `COMMIT` requests to allow some cleanup in the database. Said differently you should use one `to_sql` per chunk. It forces you to explicitely drop the table before the loop, use `if_exists="append"` and be ready to clean everything if things go wrong, but I know no better way...

Answer (score 1):

I guess your implied question is how do I fix this? Consider rephrasing it.

Anyway, I think it's just failing due to a limit, and that's it.

Consider using:

`if_exists="append"`

Comment: `if_exists="append"` unfortunately does not solve anything. I guess the question now is how to write it in chunks, the same way is it is read in chunks. Any ideas?